# How to calculate the probability of winning an election?

Tags: conditional-probability, survey, computational-statistics

I'm analyzing a survey data that contains the following 3 variables (questions):

- If the election was today who would you vote for in the following list?
  (A, B, C, D, or E)?

Let's imagine the respondent choose A in the previous item. Then, she is asked:

- What if A is not participating in the contest, who would you vote for?
  (B, C, D, or E)?

Let's imagine the respondent choose C in the previous item. Then, she is asked:

- What if A and C are not participating in the contest, who would you vote for?
  (B, D, or E)?

I have the answer for the three questions and I want to create an algorithm to help me calculate the chances of victory of A against all other candidates, the chances of B against all the others, and so on.

My goal is to report who are the most dangerous opponents of each candidate.

Anyone has an idea/suggestion?

Comment: Just make sure that you don't run into any election paradoxes with switching candidate pools.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Plackett-Luce ranking model, also known as the exploded logit model.  See the section "Ranking of Alternatives" in [Discrete choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_choice) and the paper [Bayesian inference for Plackett-Luce ranking models](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/81134/plackett.pdf).